# Multiple Views For One Controller in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a controller called `PageViewController`. Now I have created several view controllers in my storyboard. Ideally I would like to connect all of the view controllers in my storyboard to `PageViewController` and then when `PageViewController` is loaded, `PageViewController` will choose which view to display to the user.

I don't want to create the view programmatically since I'll also have to create numerous layout constraints to each view and that will be time consuming. My questions is this, since I connected multiple view controllers to `PageViewController`, is there a way for me to tell my app which view controller from the storyboard I want displayed for `PageViewController`.

Comment: You can set segue identifiers then transition to the proper view controller conditionally.

Comment: Create ViewCotroller's in storyboard and provide identifier to them, in PageViewController call the performSegue: method to navigate to corresponding view controller's.

Comment: Lyndsey, answer the question and I'll give you credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure of what you want but you can get your controller from your storyboard using its identifier :

```
let controller = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("myControllerIdentifier") as! MyControllerClass
```

You can present it using presentViewController: